# If I move a repo that's pip-installed into a conda environment, will the environment still work?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have a git repo (`repo1`) that I installed into my conda environment (`env1`) as follows:

```
conda activate env1
cd /path/to/repo1
pip install -e .
```

If I move `repo1` to a different location, `/new/path/to/repo1`, will `repo1` still be installed and working in `env1`? (And will the install still update when I update the repo, as the -e flag had ensured?)

If not, do I need to reinstall `repo1`, or can I change the path that conda's looking up somewhere?

Comment: Well, what happens if you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install -e .` Installs a python package using symlinks with absolute paths so yes if you move the directory you need to reinstall the package for it to work properly.

**Edit:** To answer your question a bit more directly, i do not think you can move the directory as paths are usually absolute inside virtual environment, you would have to edit all generated info files, scripts and symlink files to point to the new location manually, which is probably doable but a pain.

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this answered if you can update your answer with a direct response to "can I change the path that conda's looking up somewhere [without reinstalling]?". Sounds like no, but just want to check.

Comment: "*symlinks with absolute paths*" - wouldn't that imply that it should continue to work as long as on same volume? Sounds like only relative symlinks or moving to new volume would be problematic.

Comment: The links are not in the moved directory but in the env directory, so you would have to update them to point to your new location also if there are linked libraries or command line scripts you have to recreate them as well.